# Can't install package dist with composer on Bitbucket

Tags: composer-php, bitbucket

I've got a private package host on Bitbucket.

Every time I require it in another project, Composer installs the source instead of the dist. What's annoying is that I configure my `.gitattributes` to not export some folders but it does.

Here is the composer.json from the project I want to require my package

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:MyCompany/my_package.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "my/package": "^1.2",
}
```

Everything is working fine with this, except that I can't tell it to not export some folders and that I would prefer Composer to install dist instead of source.

I don't know where to go from here so any help will be much appreciated!